# Will 3ware controllers continue to rebuild when I reboot the computer?

Tags: storage, hardware-raid, 3ware

I am using a 3ware 9690SA-8I controller and one drive in my raid 6 hick uped and now the raid is rebuilding. Meanwhile I noticed I have an unfortunate combination of stupid programs and I need to reboot the OS.

When I reboot the OS, will the controller keep rebuilding or will a reboot interrupt the rebuild process? If it interrupts the rebuilding, will it pick up where it left of after the reboot, or will it start from 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebooting will clear all rebuild progress and yes it will start over at 0.

I had the same issue with the same card and other 3ware cards. Had to weigh the value of the current reboot versus waiting for rebuild again. I will admit, sometimes it was worth more to start over and other times it was worth more to wait for rebuild to finish. Depends on your use case.